# How do I catch NameError in Python?

Tags: python, class

I've been trying to write a simple program in python to use classes and test attributes. It asks the user to input one of the names, and uses that input to display 2 attributes of the name. I've tried to include a try...except block to catch the NameError that occurs when typing something that hasn't been defined as the name of an object, but I still get this traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:/Users/Bede/Documents/Technology/Programming/Python/276/testcode", line 18, in      <module>
animalName = input(">")
File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'Marmadukke' is not defined
```

I'm aware this probably isn't the best way to do things, so I'm open to all suggestions.

My full code is here:

```
class Dog(object):
    def __init__(self,name,chasesCats):
        self.name = name
        self.chasesCats = chasesCats

class Cat(object):
    def __init__(self,name,chasesMice):
        self.name = name
        self.chasesMice = chasesMice

Marmaduke = Cat("Marmaduke",True)
Timmy = Cat("Timmy",False)
Cerberus = Dog("Cerberus",True)
Max = Dog("Max",False)

print("Enter Marmaduke, Timmy, Max or Cerberus.")

animalName = input(">")
while 1:
    try:
        if isinstance(animalName,Cat):
            print("Cat")
            if animalName.chasesMice:
                print("Chases mice")
            else: print("Doesn't chase mice")
        if isinstance(animalName,Dog):
            print("Dog")
            if animalName.chasesCats:
                print("Chases cats")
            else: print("Doesn't chase cats")
        break
    except NameError:
            print("Try again!")
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm guessing you're using python2.x.  In that case, you should use `raw_input` instead of `input`.  The problem is that on python2.x, `input` calls `eval` on the data you put in.  I suppose, this means that you *could* put in the data as `"Marmaduke"` (note the quotes).  But having the program behave differently depending on whether you're using python2.x or 3.x seems undesirable.

An easy way to make the code work for both, python2.x and python3.x:

```
try:
    raw_input
except NameError:
    raw_input = input
```

Answer (score 2):

`animalName = input(">")` is outside of the try block. So the Error won't be caught.

Probably you want that inside the try block in the loop:

```
while 1:
    try:
        animalName = input(">")
        if isinstance(animalName,Cat):
```

Answer (score 1):

This line is the culprit:

```
animalName = input(">")
```

When you enter `Marmadukke`, which isn't defined yet, you get the name error, since you're trying to do:

```
animalName = Marmadukke #Not defined.
```

Wrap it in a `try/except` block:

```
try:    
        animalName = input(">")
except:    
    print("Invalid input!")
```

But to achieve this, it would be much better to store your animals to a dictionary, and retrieve only the name:

```
animals = {}

animals['Marmaduke'] = Cat("Marmaduke",True)
animals['Timmy'] = Cat("Timmy",False)
animals['Cerberus'] = Dog("Cerberus",True)
animals['Max'] = Dog("Max",False)
```

And to retrieve:

```
animalName = animals[raw_input(">")]
```

You can then put it inside your while function, and catch `KeyError` instead of `NameError`.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

For the fun and interest, I have extended your code; try tracing through it, you should learn lots ;-)

```
class Mammal(object):
    index = {}

    def __init__(self, name, chases_what=type(None)):
        Mammal.index[name] = self
        self.name = name
        self.chases_what = chases_what

    def speak(self):
        pass

    def chase(self, who):
        if isinstance(who, self.chases_what):
            self.speak()
            print('{} chases {} the {}'.format(self.name, who.name, who.__class__.__name__))
            who.speak()
        else:
            print("{} won't chase a {}".format(self.name, who.__class__.__name__))

class Mouse(Mammal):
    def speak(self):
        print('Squeak! Squeak!')

class Cat(Mammal):
    def __init__(self, name, chases=True):
        super(Cat, self).__init__(name, Mouse)
        self.chases = chases

    def chase(self, who):
        if self.chases:
            super(Cat, self).chase(who)
        else:
            print("{} won't chase anything".format(self.name))

class Dog(Mammal):
    def __init__(self, name, chases_what=Cat):
        super(Dog, self).__init__(name, chases_what)

    def speak(self):
        print('Bark! Bark!')

    def chase(self, who):
        if self is who:
            print("{} chases his own tail".format(self.name))
        else:
            super(Dog, self).chase(who)

# create animal instances        
Mouse('Jerry')
Mouse('Speedy Gonzalez')
Cat('Garfield', chases=False)
Cat('Tom')
Dog('Max')
Dog('Marmaduke', (Cat, Mouse))

def main():
    while True:
        name  = raw_input('Enter an animal name (or Enter to quit): ').strip()

        if not name:
            break

        me = Mammal.index.get(name, None)
        if me is None:
            print("I don't know {}; try again!".format(name))
            continue

        chase = raw_input('Enter who they should chase: ').strip()
        target = Mammal.index.get(chase, None)
        if target is None:
            print("I don't know {}".format(name))
        else:
            me.chase(target)

if __name__=="__main__":
    main()
```